# Nim: 'readChar deprecated'. What to use instead?

Tags: nim-lang

i'm following this guide to start with Nim by writing a brainfuck interpreter: [http://howistart.org/posts/nim/1/][1]

It all works fine, but compilation includes a warning:

> error: readChar is deprecated

Googling that message (in quotes) gives me no hits. Is there a drop in replacement for readChar?
If not, what is the easiest replacement for the same functionality? (preferably from the standard lib).

The code it's used in is:

```
proc run(skip = false): bool =
  while tapePos >= 0 and codePos < code.len:
    if tapePos >= tape.len:
      tape.add '\0'

    if code[codePos] == '[':
      inc codePos
      let oldPos = codePos
      while run(tape[tapePos] == '\0'):
        codePos = oldPos
    elif code[codePos] == ']':
      return tape[tapePos] != '\0'
    elif not skip:
      case code[codePos]
      of '+': inc tape[tapePos]
      of '-': dec tape[tapePos]
      of '>': inc tapePos
      of '<': dec tapePos
      of '.': stdout.write tape[tapePos]
      of ',': tape[tapePos] = stdin.readChar
      else: discard

    inc codePos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use `readChars` to achieve the same semantics (untested, but should work):

```
proc run(skip = false): bool =
  while tapePos >= 0 and codePos < code.len:
    if tapePos >= tape.len:
      tape.add '\0'

    if code[codePos] == '[':
      inc codePos
      let oldPos = codePos
      while run(tape[tapePos] == '\0'):
        codePos = oldPos
    elif code[codePos] == ']':
      return tape[tapePos] != '\0'
    elif not skip:
      case code[codePos]
      of '+': inc tape[tapePos]
      of '-': dec tape[tapePos]
      of '>': inc tapePos
      of '<': dec tapePos
      of '.': stdout.write tape[tapePos]
      of ',': discard stdin.readChars(tape, tapePos, 1)
      else: discard

    inc codePos
```

For context as to why this was deprecated, see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186397/nim-readchar-deprecated-what-to-use-instead/48213399#comment83407398_48187759)

Comment: I tried this, but got `Error: expression expected, but found keyword discard`. Removing the discard then gives a type mismatch `got (int) but expected char = Char`. I tried casting tapePos to char, but that gave a different type error.

Comment: hrm, can you gist your code (or pastebin it somewhere)?

Comment: Ah, I still had the "tape[tapePos] = <changed code>". Removing that fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Yobmod Looks like you've inspired a change: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/7072 :)

Answer (score 0):

Nim documentation suggests to use readBuffer.

> proc readBuffer(f: File; buffer: pointer; len: Natural): int {..}
>   reads len bytes into the buffer pointed to by buffer. Returns the
>   actual number of bytes that have been read which may be less than len
>   (if not as many bytes are remaining), but not greater.

Comment: But readBuffer takes a file as an input arg, so how is it doing the same thing?

Comment: readBuffer takes a `File` and stdin is a `File`.

See https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#stdin

Comment: This isn't a good alternative as it is somewhat unsafe because it takes a ``pointer``, and as @Yobmod noticed it doesn't really match ``readChar``.

It's unfortunate that this was deprecated, the reasoning for the deprecation is that ``readChar`` is slow but there isn't really an alternative. You can see my discussion about this with Nim's creator here: https://irclogs.nim-lang.org/11-01-2018.html#17:32:03